# Keyword using different libraries objects

Tags: python, robotframework

i have two libs, both with open() method:

```
Library Menu.py
Library Submenu.py

*** Test Cases ***
MenuOpen
    open Menu

SubmenuOpen
    open Submenu
*** Keywords ***
    open
    [Arguments]    ${library_object}
    ${library_object}.open()
```

(this is simplified example, that is why keyword contains only one line, yet it shows my issue). How to create and pass the library object, to make this code actually work?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right.
When you import your module, you can either do a basic:

```
import myModule1, my Module2
```

Then your Menu will actually be referred as myModule1.Menu and myModule2.Menu

or you can import as, or even from/import/as, for example :

```
from myModule1 import Menu as Menu
from myModule2 import Menu as SubMenu
```

Comment: This is python's code. How to make this in Robot Framework syntax? I want to import module and get reference to it. Simply i need instance of module in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

To get the library instance you can use the [Get library instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) keyword from the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html). With the instance, you can then use the [Call method](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Call%20Method) keyword to call the keyword in that library:

```
open
    [Arguments]    ${library_object}
    ${lib}=        Get library instance    ${library_object}
    call method    ${lib}    open
```

You could also just pass in the name, and use Run keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
open
    [Arguments]    ${library_object}
    run keyword    ${library_object}.open
```

If you want to avoid such trickery you can directly call the `open` keyword of whichever library you want by fully qualifying it:

```
*** Test cases ***
MenuOpen
    Menu.open

SubmentOpen
    Submenu.open
```